# When did the term "order" come into use as the highest exponent in an expansion?

Tags: mathematics, terminology

Answer(s) to the question [What is a 3rd-order Fresnel lens?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/472415/83380) are disappointing to me, in that the term *3rd order* does not refer to anything like a third-order series expansion.

But this leads me to a new question: When did the use of an expression like "third order approximation" come into use in naming such a thing as a third-order series expansion?

And if it can be narrowed down sufficiently, is there any idea of who it was who first used it this way?

Comment: According to [Jeff Miller](http://jeff560.tripod.com/): ORDER (degree) is found in English in 1706 in Ditton, Fluxions 22: "An Infinitesimal of another Order or Degree" and ibid. 123: "These sorts of [Exponential] Quantities are of several Orders or Degrees" [OED].

Comment: @MichaelBächtold that certainly sounds exactly like what I'm after. OED means he is quoting the Oxford English Dictionary?

Comment: With "lenses, divided into four orders based on their size and focal length" Fresnel used the original Latin meaning of *ordo*, row, line, rank, which predates the order of approximation by centuries, see [Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/order).

Comment: @uhoh Yes, OED means Oxford English Dictionary. http://jeff560.tripod.com/sources.html

Comment: @Conifold that's wonderful! You are welcome to post an answer at the question in Physics SE with that, but I am not able to see that quote at the link you've provided.

Comment: The quote is from your own link. The dictionary just provides the description of the sense of the word used in it.

Comment: @Conifold Oh I see. Then it will certainly be welcome as a comment or an answer there as well, thank you! The reference to the Fresnel lens is background for this question only. It explains how I got to the point of asking this question. But this question itself is not about lenses.

Comment: No, I haven't read that. It is a little ambiguous in the post what "such a thing" refers to. In any case, no harm in people finding out both things.

Comment: @Conifold I've made an edit, how does that look?